# Get element by tag name shorthand?

Tags: javascript, dom, tags, element, getelementsbytagname

I don't know what it's called, but I know that there's a way to get elements based on their tags without `getElementsByTagName`. It returns the same thing, but it's shorter and I'm using tags a lot in my project. What I'm talking about is `document.frames[x]` and `document.images[x]`, but with other elements, like `document.b[x]` or `document.a[x]`. Seeing as `document.images` isn't the same as the `<img>` tag, it seems like if there are more they'd be named differently as well. Would anyone happen to know what it's called when using this method and/or have a list of accepted tags? Thanks.

P.S. Please do not suggest using a library such as jQuery. This project is meant to be a learning experience, so I want to use regular JavaScript.

Comment: Why not just create a shorter alias to `document.getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: Where did you find this shorter way?  Are you thinking of `document.getElementByID`?

Comment: I know how to make a function and make it shorter, but as stated the project is to help me learn as much about JavaScript as I can and this is something that I know exists but don't fully understand, nor do I know any guides and therefor I ask here for someone who may know about it. The shorter way isn't getElement, it's just like the two examples included in my question.

Comment: What you're talking about is **not** "regular JavaScript", but "things that browsers provide to the JavaScript runtime."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere in the answers, this doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript really, these are DOM properties and methods accessible via [the JavaScript language binding for the DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html).

With reference to addressing elements such as `document.frames[x]` (*note that this is incorrect, it should be [`window.frames[x]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.frames)*) and `document.images[x]` - these are [Document Object/HTML Collections](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-26809268) and the W3C standard includes only `images, applets, links, forms` and `anchors`.

So unless I'm looking in completely the wrong place, from what I can tell from the [DOM-1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-26809268) and [DOM-2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26809268) specs, there doesn't seem to any way of arbitrarily addressing elements by tag name the way that you remember doing.

**Update**

The [MDC entry on `HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection) is more understandable; it reads

> The following lists each item (and its specific properties) which return an HTMLCollection: Document (images, applets, links, forms, anchors); form (elements); map (areas); table (rows, tBodies); tableSection (rows); row (cells)

Comment: JavaScript is all about the DOM. The language is ECMAScript, using it with a DOM is javascript (or Javascript or JavaScript, whatever).

Comment: @RobG No, the standardized version of JavaScript is named ECMAScript but to most people, it's all JavaScript. Saying that *it's all about the DOM* doesn't change the fact that these are DOM collections and not part of the JavaScript language - if you were using JS in a different environment, you might not see these. And if you were using some other language binding for the DOM, you would still have access to these named collections. So yes, I feel justified in making the distinction between the DOM and JavaScript and saying that this is not JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy - JavaScript™ is ECMAScript in a browser interacting with the DOM. The word has become a generic term with various forms of captialisation. Node.js describes itself as "Evented I/O for V8 JavaScript", where V8 is Google's "open source JavaScript engine". Where does it say javascript "doesn't have anything to do with the DOM"?

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - yes, a down vote for "this doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript". The W3C DOM specs are language neutral, but the OP has tagged the question "JavaScript" and said "I want to use regular JavaScript". Also, there are many extensions to the W3C APIs that are widely implemented such as the DOM 0 features, innerHTML, canvas, XMLHttpRequest and so on so JavaScript is a bigger beast than just the W3C APIs. Most such extensions are now included in HTML5, which is effectively an "as-built" DOM spec with a bit of a wish list added on. It is also not a W3C standard.

Comment: @RobG well Node.js is a server-side environment that, unless you drop in one of various "virtual DOM" libraries, has nothing to do with DOM manipulation.

Comment: @RobG It's been a while since we had this discussion but I wanted to point you to [this page on the MDC Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript) that attempts to clarify the confusion between JavaScript and the DOM. The core point it makes (which I feel is relevant) is *While JavaScript is the programming language which will allow you to operate on the DOM objects and to manipulate them programmatically, the DOM will provide you with methods and properties to retrieve, modify, update, and delete parts of the document you are working on.*

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is accessing the DOM elements is, well, the DOM API and not something built into the JavaScript language. For example, the PDF API exposes it's own DOM that is different from the (X)HTML DOM which can be accessed via JavaScript but which does not have the functions mentioned in this answer (`getElementById()`, `getElementsByTagName()` etc). What you're seeing is the JavaScript language binding for the (X)HTML DOM exposed by browsers.

Comment: no.good.at.coding - +1 for persistence. JavaScript™ is not a language, it's Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript. Google's V8 is another ECMAScript implementation. When the Node.js people call it "JavaScript" (I would write it "javascript" but there are differing views about that), they are using it as a generic term for an EMCAScript implementation. V8 isn't JavaScript, it's V8.

Comment: Your distinction between JavaScript™ and the W3C DOM API is fine, but not relevant here. The OP was about element collections in a DOM, i.e. about javascript in general, not specifically about JavaScript™ or W3C DOM APIs. Given that various javascript (i.e. ECMAScript in a browser) implementations offer non-standard APIs, it's misleading to say that just because a question isn't specifically about JavaScript™ and uses a W3C DOM API as an example that it isn't about javascript (the generic term for ECMAScript in a browser).

Comment: I see your point about some things - as for the rest, I guess we can just agree to disagree :)

Answer (score 6):

Other than other JavaScript libraries creating these shorthands, I am not aware of any that are built into the language. It would be trivial to map this to your own shorthand:

```
var $ = document.getElementsByTagName;

// you can then use it like so:
$('SPAN').// and so on
```

Other than this, there is no built-in array-like access to all of the tags in the document:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/document.shtml

Comment: While I was unaware that could be done and it's a nifty bit a knowledge to have, I still am curious about how many of these built-in alternatives exist. Two already exist that I know of, as mentioned in my question. I'd like more information on that rather than alternatives.

Comment: Actually, you can't do that because `getElementsByTagName` would be called without the correct context (`document`). `var $ = function () { return document.getElementByTagName.apply(document, arguments); }`

Comment: Agreed, I am merely pointing out how trivial it would be to create a mapping of this nature.

Comment: And let's all agree to standardise on $ being getElementById, right?

Comment: mplungian - There is no such "standarisation". In probably the most used javascript library, *$* is not *getElementById*, it is an overloaded identifier that does many things, one of which is to return an object with numeric properties referencing elements matching a supplied selector. It has many other uses and hence meanings.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own reference,

```
document.tag = document.getElementsByTagName;
```

or a wrapper,

```
function tag(name) {
    return document.getElementsByTagName(name);
}
```

The only APIs I know of that support querying by element name are,

**DOM**

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

**CSS Selectors**

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)

**XPath**

[evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

**E4X**

(mozilla only, and doesn't work with the DOM yet)